# Connecting MySQL Workbench with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I have read and tried prior suggestions.

Here is what I have done.

1. I signed up for a static IP through a Proxy Server (that uses Port 3128)
2. I have tested that static IP is working (verified with several IP look up services)
3. I have chanced the authorized root password
4. I have tried setting the client host to Proxy Server value on the authorized users.
5. I have white labeled/authorized the static IP in Cloud SQL
6. I have tried both the IPv6 and IPv4 addresses from Cloud SQL in MySQL Workbench

I never get passed the error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 22 when using the IPv6 and Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 when using the IPv4

As an aside, I was able to authorize Zapier IP and have tested a webhook to Cloud SQL

Comment: Have you walk these steps https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client

Comment: Yes. I have MySQL and the Community Server.

Comment: As I mention above, I have changed the root user password in Cloud SQL and made use of these credentials in the Workbench connection.  I have tested my static proxy IP and white labeled this within Cloud SQL. I have tried to use both the IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. I have tested MySQL on my localhost and that works smashingly well, both from command line and Workbench.

Comment: BTW - I have also tried restarting the service

Comment: I would be happy to open up an aws 3306 if you wanted to hit it to rule out something

Comment: Drew that would be great. Can we try that on Monday?

Comment: Drew - I was able to get it to work, albeit only with my current Dynamic IP. In addition to white labeling the IP in Access panel, I also needed to create a new user (root) and then use the advanced feature to add the IP into client host on that specific user.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your description: did you whitelist *your* computer's IP address? There are sites that will tell you which IP address your computer is using, and that is the address you should use under the Access Control panel.

Comment: My comments #1, 2 are to indicate that I received a static proxy IP and that I tested it with a service ( http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test) to make sure that was my IP.My comment #5 indicates that I white listed my computer IP on Cloud SQL, so this is exactly what I stated.  Yesterday, I turned off the static IP proxy and white labeled the current Dynamic IP assigned to me in Cloud SQL and was able to connect. This tells me that there is something wrong with the proxy. Also continuing to use the Dynamic IP is less than ideal for obvious reasons

Comment: Can you please clearly indicate from _where_ you are attempting to connect to Cloud SQL and _what_ is providing you the static IP service? Does that service works for any TCP connections? If it only works for HTTP then that might explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Hey folks - I actually figured out what the issue is. In Google Cloud SQL, not only must you white label the IP of the accessing application, you need to specify a new user such as root, with or without a password and then add the client host IP in the advanced options. You can't simply use an existing user and password.

Comment: However, I was only able to get this to work with my current dynamic IP. Google does not seem to like the static proxy IP.

Comment: Razvan, I got the Static IP from a Proxy service that says it should work for both HTTP and TCP.